# Can the del operator be "separated" like this?

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-operators

In class, we were asked to prove the identity $\nabla\times(\Omega\vec{V})=\Omega(\nabla\times\vec{V})-\vec{V}\times\nabla\Omega$. One of the possible approaches involved separating the del operator into two operators,

\begin{equation}\nabla\equiv\nabla_{\Omega}+\nabla_{\vec{V}}\end{equation}

where $\nabla_{\Omega}$ differentiates $\Omega$ and leaves it operates on $\vec{V}$ zero, and vice versa. I know how to prove the identity, once I accept that $\nabla\equiv\nabla_{\Omega}+\nabla_{\vec{V}}$, but I find ti difficult to convince myself that it is true. Can del be separated like this?

Comment: Please let me know how to improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer you can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

The Del operator $\nabla$ operates on the independent coordinate variables, $x$, $y$, and $z$,not the dependent variables $\vec V(x,y,z)$ and $\Omega(x,y,z)$.  So, we have

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times (\Omega \vec V)&=\sum_{i=1}^3 \hat x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\times \left(\Omega \sum_{j=1}^3 \hat x_jV_j\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 (\hat x_i \times \hat x_j )\left(\Omega \frac{\partial V_j}{\partial x_i}+V_j \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial x_i}\right)\\\\
&=\Omega \nabla \times \vec V+\nabla \Omega \times \vec V\\\\
&=\Omega \nabla \times \vec V-\vec V\times \nabla \Omega 
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @TonyK It certainly does.  The question is "Can the del operator be “separated” like this?"  The solution posted herein answers that with a "No."  Read "not the dependent variables."

Comment: @NX37B Please let me know how to improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer you can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.